# Use integrability condition to deduce limit result

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\geqslant0$ and $(\mu_{n})$ sequence of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$.

Show that the condition $\sup\limits_{n} \int fd\mu_{n} <\infty $ implies that

$\lim\limits_{R\rightarrow\infty} \limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d} \setminus B(0,R) } fd\mu_{n} = 0 $

I think intuitively it makes sense but I cannot explain it in detail using math notation. Could someone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is true. Let $d=1, f \equiv 1$, and $\mu_n = \delta_n$. Then $\int fd\mu_n = 1$ for each $n$ and for each $R > 0$, $\limsup_n \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus B(0,R)} fd\mu_n = 1$.

Comment: You are right..

Comment: what if I want to prove the same but for $f(x)=|x|^{p} $ ?

Comment: @vl.ath  Don't you get the same issue

Comment: @vl.ath is everything clear now?

Comment: yes thanks! my mistake asking asking  about |x|^p.. it doesn't satisfy the condition for $f_{n}=\delta_{n}$